# Could we ask question related to broken functionality?

Tags: discussion

I will like to know if is acceptable to post broken functionality questions.  A question related to functionality that is not working on a given implementation of wordpress.  I have a few of those, I don't know where they belong.

An example will be: [Editing a profile is not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10550/the-super-admin-cannot-update-or-create-users-how-do-i-fix-this)

This is a problem with a given implementation, since this functionality works in all other instances, there is a specific problem with this one instance of wordpress.

I really need a forum to post these, but I can't find one forum that will actually get answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _not working for a given implementation_. Could you please rephrase or add an example?

Comment: yes, this needs examples

Comment: I just added a few more bits of information.

Comment: This looks like a "troubleshooting" problem, where you need some iterations to figure out the root problem ("Try this and tell me what it gives"). The Q@A format is not so suited for that, but I solved this in the past by going to the chat, doing the troubleshooting there, and linking to the conversation in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a perfectly fine question to me.

But note that while there is nothing wrong (that I see) with asking such question, it might be not very likely to get good answers. Unless the issue is typical or question gives clear leads on what might possibly be the cause.

Comment: Thanks Rarst, I understand the popularity issue.  If you look online you will see that there are more people with the issue, and the most common answer is remove wordpress and re-install.  Which is not acceptable to me.  If i get an answer here, SE will be my new place to hang-out.

Comment: I agree @Geo and @Rarst. If we allow these questions, then it's a good step to out SEO'ing WP.org about support questions.

Comment: @Zack - I like how you think!